# Fetching zero core data objects returning error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My application is still in development stage, and I'm trying to do register user. I want to check if there is an existing user in core data, if result is returning 0, then I will add a new user. If not, I will update the existing user that I fetch from server side. I also know that currently, my core data is **empty**. However, when I tried to fetch data, at the line

`let searchResult = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [User]`

It goes to the catch statement and prints error.

> Error Domain=Foundation._GenericObjCError Code=0 "(null)"

Below are my codes. Tried searching on Google for the exact error code, but I can't find any.

```
func SaveToCoreData(){
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "User")
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    do{
        let searchResult = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [User]
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: managedContext)
        let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)

        if(searchResult.count == 0){
            newUser.setValue(emailField, forKey: "email")
            newUser.setValue(jsonReply["profilePicture"].stringValue, forKey: "profilePicture")

            do{
                try managedContext.save()
            } catch let error as NSError{
                ShowAlert(title: "", message: error.description)
            }
        }
        else if(searchResult.count == 1){
            let updateUser = user[0]

            updateUser.setValue(emailField, forKey: "email")
            updateUser.setValue(jsonReply["profilePicture"].stringValue, forKey: "profilePicture")

            do{
                try managedContext.save()
                self.ShowTabBar()
            } catch let error as NSError{
                ShowAlert(title: "", message: error.description)
            }
        }

    } catch let error as NSError{
        print(error)
    }
```

}

Comment: Since you didn't store any data to the DB. Use`try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [User]` rather than `as!`.

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: https://www.osstatus.com/. Use this to check any errors from framework.

Comment: @jo3birdtalk did you solve the problem?